# When creating a new Activity why do we need to cast an EditText object as an EditText object?

Tags: java, android, xml

This is part of the Android Studio Training.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

The full method is:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
  String message = editText.getText().toString();
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
```

More information for this training project can be found at:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 3):

`findViewById()` returns a `View` by default, which doesn't include methods like `getText()` for example.

`EditText` is a subclass of `View`, which is why this casting works.

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.TextView
           ↳    android.widget.EditText
```

Comment: Also, I don't know how much about OOP and Java does the question owner knows. So, by casting that, all the EditText specific methods like .setTextSize(), .getText(), and so on will be avaliable.

Comment: I have some experience with Java. It's been several years so I am trying to brush up and dive into Android at the same time. Thank you all for the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The method `findViewById` returns a `View`, which is the generic Class for **any** View in Android. That means that `ListView`, `TextView`, `TabHost`, etc etc etc are all `View`s.

You have to cast it so that the object you are working with has access to the specific methods of that `View`. For instance, `ListView` has methods that `EditText` doesn't have.

You can cast that without worries because you **know** that the object you are working with is **indeed** an `EditText`. You know that because you have explictly defined an `EditText` when writing the layout, and have assigned an ID for this `View`, which you'll use later to identify this exact same View.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know it is an `EditText`?  How does Android know it?

In fact, Android does *not* know it unless you tell it so, because the return type of `findViewById()` is `View`.  Although `EditText` is one kind of `View`, there are others, and custom ones can be defined.  The cast tells Android that you promise the `View` returned will be an `EditText`, so it can treat it as one.  It requires you to cast explicitly in part for your own protection -- so that you know you are injecting your own knowledge / assumptions into the program.

If your promise is discovered to be in error, then Android will throw a `ClassCastException` to chastise you about that.